# React JS - Firebase Error: invalid document reference. document references must have an even number of segments, but users has 1

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was referencing the a user document in my users collection in a useEffect hook as shown below:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getCart = async (id) => {
      const userRef = doc(db, 'users', id);
      const userSnap = await getDoc(userRef);
      if (userSnap.exists()) {
        const userData = userSnap.data();

        dispatchCartAction({type: "MERGE_WITH_DB", cart: userData.cart })
      } else {
        console.log("No such document!");
      }
    };

    if (authCtx.isLoggedIn) {
      getCart(authCtx.userId);
    } else {
      console.log("from: local storage");
    }
  }, [authCtx]);
```

And I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Even number of segment means you are using slashes unproperly. either collection/document/ should be collection/document, never starts with slash or end with slash at document